# Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env'

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to set up es6 transpilation from gulp.
I'm setting up a completely minimal test just to get babel working with gulp.

I installed the modules like this:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-cli  gulp-babel@next @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

I have this gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

This setup is slightly adapted from the babel documentation:
https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

When I run 'gulp', I get this output:

```
[20:16:25] Using gulpfile ~/play/react/babeltest/gulpfile.js
[20:16:25] Starting 'default'...
[20:16:25] 'default' errored after 23 ms
[20:16:25] Error in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from '/home/bobdobbs/play/babeltest'
```

How do I get this working?